# find free time in table 1 by comparing table two working time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

```
create table timetable( work_date date, tech_id int,
    block_1_firsthalf_start_time datetime,  block_1_end_time datetime,
    block_2_secondhalf_start_time datetime, block_2_end_time datetime,
    block_3_over_time datetime, block_3_over_end_time datetime,
    block_4_first_break_start_time datetime,    block_4_first_break_end_time datetime,
    block_5_second_break_start_time datetime,   block_5_second_break_end_time datetime)

insert into timetable values(
'8/6/2013', 1,
    '8/6/13 6:00 AM',   '8/6/13 10:00 AM',
    '8/6/13 11:00 AM',  '8/6/13 6:00 PM',
    '8/6/13 6:30 PM',   '8/6/13 8:00 PM'
    '8/6/13 7:00 AM',   '8/6/13 8:00 AM',
    '8/6/13 5:00 PM',   '8/6/13 5:30 PM')
```

another table:

```
create table jobtable(tech_id   int,Job_starting_time datetime, Job_end_time datetime)

insert into jobtable values(1,  '8/6/13 7:00 AM','8/6/13 8:00 AM')
```

Now  need to find free time in a day for the employee.pl share how can we make it.

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure should be normalised to a list of blocks/jobs

```
TechID   StartDateTime   EndDateTime
1        2013-6-8 06:00  2013-6-8 10:00
1        2013-6-8 11:00  2013-6-8 18:00
...
```

Then it is much easier to find blocks of time that don't intersect with the existing data, and you don't restrict your techs to a limited number of time periods for each day.

Comment: we will follow this in future. can you provide the query to retreive the required data.

Comment: Your data structure is too broken to do that reliably!